# Java - Prevent HashMap from Affecting Original Value

Tags: java, hashmap, pass-by-reference

I am getting an object from a HashMap, modifying it, and then saving it to the HashMap under a different key.
However, my changes also affect the original object.

My code is as follows:

Dog.java:

```
public class Dog {
    public String id = "";
    public String name = "";
}
```

MyApp.java:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog1 = new Dog();
        dog1.id = "d1";
        dog1.name = "dog1";
        System.out.println(dog1.id); // d1
        System.out.println(dog1.name); // dog1

        HashMap<String, Dog> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(dog1.id, dog1);

        Dog dog2 = map.get(dog1.id);
        dog2.id = "d2";
        dog2.name = "dog2";
        System.out.println(dog2.id); // d2
        System.out.println(dog2.name); // dog2

        map.put(dog2.id, dog2);

        System.out.println(dog1.id); // d2
        System.out.println(dog1.name); // dog2
        System.out.println(dog2.id); // d2
        System.out.println(dog2.name); // dog2
    }
}
```

I remember reading that HashMaps pass values by reference/pointers.

How do I prevent changes to my modified object from affecting the original object?

***UPDATE:*** So it seems the line `dog2 = map.get(dog1.id);` is equivalent to `Dog dog2 = dog1;`. I'll just create a new instance and manually copy the fields I need then. Many thanks to all who helped!

Comment: you'll have to create a _new_ object

Comment: Sounds like you're looking to have two dogs in the map.  But you only ever created one.  You're just shuffling him around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dog2` is actually a `dog1` instance, due to this code

```
Dog dog2 = map.get(dog1.id);
```

above code will make `dog2` become alias name for `dog1` that have same reference/pointer. to fix those need to create new instance for `dog2`

```
Dog dog2 = new Dog();
```